# Debugger.Break(); does not break

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2017

I'm using Debug.Break() to track down bugs in my code. I want to insert a "Halt" in the Visual Studio IDE so that I can inspect values.

Now I'm in a situation where the IDE just goes over Debug.Break() without stopping:

```
        _lrNavMeshPath = nParentForLineRenderer.gameObject.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();

        if (_lrNavMeshPath == null)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        }
```

What might be the reason why the IDE just goes over this line without stopping?
I have set a breakpoint at this line, so I see that this line is called.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and in again? Im just joking - be sure you have the correct run settings.
Run it as debug and not release, remove additional runtime options and rebuilding the project may help

Comment: Are you attaching Visual Studios to Unity when your scene is running?  Also, Debug.Break (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.Break.html) might be helpful to you as it will pause the runtime and let you inspect values in the inspector.

Comment: For sanity sake: Does your if statement actually pass? Did you attach your VS to Unity? And is it actually attached to the *correct* Unity. Sometimes when Unity crashes/closes while VS still runs it will reference to the previous instance of Unity. You can select the "correct" version by hitting the dropdown arrow next to attach, or restart VS.

Comment: @remy_rm I'm still buried in other things and will report back when I have tested some more.

Comment: @Eddge Yes of course I'm attaching VS to Unity, and I can inspect the values and set breakpoints. It all works fine, but the debugger just isn't breaking on System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

Comment: Also, VS IDE doesn't break if an exceptions occur. Instead it, it just skips out of the failing void.

Comment: use Debugger.Launch();